# How to double space as ctrl key?

Tags: autohotkey

I want the space key to work like Ctrl after 200 ms of being pressed. So, in theory it should work like this:

```
while space key is press down {
    for first 200 ms {
        if another key is pressed or space key released {
            work like normal space
            go no further
        }
    }
    after first 200 ms {
        if another key <Key> is pressed {
            Send Ctrl+Key
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible with AutoHotKey?

Answer (score 0):

At least part of this is possible with AutoHotkey, the below fulfills everything except 'if another key is pressed'. It might be possible if you made every key a hotkey and then used [A_PriorHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#PriorHotkey). Or perhaps there is another way I haven't thought of.

```
$Space::
KeyWait, Space, T2

if(ErrorLevel) {
    Input, SingleKey, L1, {LControl}{RControl}{LAlt}{RAlt}{LShift}{RShift}{LWin}{RWin}{AppsKey}{F1}{F2}{F3}{F4}{F5}{F6}{F7}{F8}{F9}{F10}{F11}{F12}{Left}{Right}{Up}{Down}{Home}{End}{PgUp}{PgDn}{Del}{Ins}{BS}{CapsLock}{NumLock}{PrintScreen}{Pause}
    Send {Ctrl down}%SingleKey%{Ctrl up}
} else {
    Send {Space}
}
return
```

I took the input part from [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Input.htm#ExAnyKey).